# Why can the person asking the question on Meta, choose what answer is "correct"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

**Edit**:

*The feature request is to disable the "Accepted Answer" functionality here on meta only.*

** Edit two **

It has been pointed out, that (technically) there is no official indicator of a "correct" answer on stackoverflow, only "accepted" answers.  A subtle distinction, but an important one.  However, in that case, the big green check mark could inadvertently be very deceptive.

**Original question**:

And why is there even the functionality to mark an answer as "correct" here on meta?  Theoretically, a question marked as "correct" could much have fewer up-votes, than another answer that is *not* marked as correct.

Shouldn't the people who run stackoverflow choose what answer on meta is correct?

I viewed all the possible questions that were shown to this title, plus I did a search on:

- Who can mark a meta question correct?
- Who decides what meta answer is correct?
- Who can mark my question as correct?
- Who can mark my question as correct on meta?

I didn't see anything that I felt came even close to addressing these questions.

Maybe it's just an issue of wanting consistency in the voting system, or a programming issue?

I'm suggesting that on meta, there should not be the functionality of marking the question correct, unless it's an answer that is officially sanctioned by the people in charge at stackoverflow.

Theatrically, I guess that if someone answered my question with a really stupid answer, I could mark it as correct?  Even if it got lots of down votes?  Or maybe I could answer this question myself, and then mark it as correct?

In general, the most up-voted answer may be the answer marked as correct.  That's fine.  But every time I see an answer marked as correct here on meta, I get a little twinge of wondering whether the way this is structured is open to manipulation.

Personally, it kind of degrades the legitimacy of what is a "correct" answer, for the person asking the question to be able to mark the correct answer, at least here on meta.  If I'm wrong; it that's not the case, please excuse me, and I'll delete the question.

Comment: Because "correct" is the wrong word here. I don't think the documentation for the accept feature even uses that word, ever, but for starters the tooltip says "best answer" rather than "correct answer".

Comment: What's the feature request here? I'd love to vote on one, but I am failing to parse it out of the question text...

Comment: The feature request is to disable the "correct answer" functionality here on meta only.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

That's just the way it is.  Stop whining and get used to it.

As you can see in this situation, it's possible to have an answer that is marked with the big green check mark, that is actually not the popular answer.  So, the big green check mark can be sort of deceptive.  Most of the time, the big green check mark agrees with the votes, but the system is open to manipulation with this set up.  At the very least, the big green check mark, gives most users the incorrect appearance of an answer that is "correct".

For programming questions, where the answer either fixes the code or doesn't, the big green check mark giving the appearance of a "correct" answer is fine.
But here on Meta, it's more subjective.  And whether the person asking the question marked an answer as "accepted" has legitimacy issues.  It's really meaningless that the person asking the question marked an answer as "accepted".  Which is proven in this case.

Okay, so I can answer my own question here on meta.  And it looks like I can mark it as correct.  But I need to wait a couple of days.  I'm just trying to make a point here.

Comment: ...which I'm missing., sadly.

Comment: @Sandy you can also do that on the regular site.

Comment: This is a miserable conclusion of a legitimate question. And I didn't need any of this to get your point.

Answer (score 13):

You're rambling on a bit here, but you've arrived at the paradox that is the accepted answer.  It doesn't exactly mean much of anything except to the OP; the community will express its agreement with their own votes.

If anyone *exclusively* looks at an accepted answer as the source of correct and canonical truth, then they're missing out on a lot of other bits and bobs.  That goes double for here, since there are a lot of great answers which aren't accepted, but do go to shape and influence behaviors on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sometimes OP accepts the official response even if they don't actually agree with it... which in turn may attract more downvotes.

Comment: "accepted answers are a fine social contract, but not a good data point for question or answer quality" ([Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/165773 "quote source"))

Comment: This is the most upvoted answer, but it is obviously the wrong answer.  It doesn't have the big green check mark beside it.  Please see correct answer.

Comment: @SandyGood:  I think you missed my point.  "Correct" is really a metric of whether or not the OP understands and agrees with the answer, as well as the community weighing in to the response.  Not everyone needs to agree with the accepted answer on this question; it may even be the case that the community *disagrees* with it.

Comment: I agree with your answer.  Maybe you assumed that I had a problem with your answer.  I don't.  I'm being a little snarky and sarcastic about the whole situation, because I think that there is an entrenched mentality here that has become unwilling to be unbiased in evaluating situations.

Comment: You keep using the word "correct". I do not think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of restating the obvious, I think you're suffering from a misunderstanding of what the green check mark means.

The check mark next to an answer simply indicates that the answer was "accepted" by the person asking the question and has no bearing on whether the answer was correct or not.

Note that none of the documentation related to accepting answers uses the word "correct" at any point:

[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Note that the tootip on the check mark doesn't use the word "correct" either:

[image]

---

---

Now that we've established that accepting an answer doesn't mean that it is correct, your next question will probably be:

> What does it look like when a post on Meta is "correct" or that it is
> in fact the "official position of the community"?

This can take a few forms depending on the type of post. For questions look for the tags:

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq)
[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)
[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Answers can be a little more tricky. Usually, but certainly not always, the top voted answer is *most* in line with community consensus.

On rare occasions an SE staff member may comment or edit in a note about a suggestion in an answer being implemented. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186538/217863 for an example of this.

Comment: Good point.  There is a subtle distinction.  Indeed, I am "suffering" from a misunderstanding.  I'd be curious to determine how much "suffering" there is from other users over the real meaning of the big green check mark.  I have wrongly interpreted the big green check mark as indicating the "correct" answer.  So, I guess there is no indicator at all really for a correct answer.  Technically.  You bring up a good point.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, acceptance really doesn't mean that much on Meta, and I say that as someone who has accepted, and had accepted, his fair share of answers. On feature requests or bug reports, the checkmark is basically just given to the most persuasive argument for the position the requester eventually adopts, unless there's a somewhat acceptable official response (in which case that usually gets the nod). On discussions, who knows! For support, it's usually for something reasonably verifiable, but there's seldom any real debate for any length of time about whether an answer is correct.

Comment: This is precisely the problem.  For meta regulars, who *know* that the acceptance means nothing and that they should be looking past the first answer of a question, it's not a problem, but for non-meta regulars it can give the false impression that the accepted asnwer is the community position, even when its not.